# How to set a scene rotation point in trimesh?

Tags: trimesh

Is it possible to specify a scene rotation point other than (0, 0, 0)?

I can set camera view to the point i need, by scene rotation is going around (0,0, 0) coords.

As example in pyrender i can set view_center, is it any same options in trimesh?